# python3 default to ascii with uwsgi-emperor

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, uwsgi

using:
postgres 9.5
psycopg2 2.6.2
python 3.4.2
system (debian jessie) locale: en_US.UTF-8
python's sys.stdout.encoding is UTF-8

database is UTF8, I have entries with é, ç ,è, etc...

```
pgcur.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")
rows = pgcur.fetchall()
for r in rows:
    print(r)
```

gives an error:
**UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encore character '\xe9' in position 521: ordinal not in range(128)**

I don't understand, psycopg2 connection encoding is UTF8, database is UTF8, python3 is by default string unicode... why there's ascii codec involved ?

```
print(r.encoding('utf8'))
```

solves the issue, but I don't remember having to do that with postgresql 9.4 (and same psycopg2/python releases)

do I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with upgrading from postgres 9.4 to 9.5...
It was uwsgi-emperor configuration by default :

```
autoload = true
```

that, for an unknow reason, misses locale loading.
With that option, python3.4 interpreter returns (None, None) when locale.getlocale() is called, so it default to ANSI_X3.4-1968

```
#autload = true
plugins = python34
```

solves the problem, and locale.getlocale() returns OS defined locale (UTF-8 in this specific case)

Answer (score 0):

If the error is on the `print`, `print` encodes Unicode strings to the terminal's encoding.  If the terminal is misconfigured (are you on Linux??), it could be choosing `ascii` instead of the typical `utf8` configuration of a Linux terminal.  Check the `LANG` environment variable.

Comment: could be a reason, true, but I have only one locale installed on my system,  and it's UTF8

Comment: @comte, was the error on the `print`?  Did you check that `LANG` was correct?

Comment: yes i checked $LANG is correct. but is not on print only, when send variable to Bottle template, he gives me that error also. what's weird I never had this error with postgresql 9.4 (and same python code, same system)

Comment: If this is not printing to a terminal, Python won't detect the encoding and default to `ascii`.  You can override `sys.stdout` to encoding in UTF-8 instead: `sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')`

Comment: print(sys.stdout.encoding) results UTF-8.

Comment: @comte, that's used if printing to a terminal.  Are you?  If not, you'll get `ascii`.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment, it is not printing (because the error) but is intented to print to a terminal indeed.